# On a reference request for a converge theorem regarding gradient descent.

Tags: reference-request, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Polyak in his book *Introduction to Optimization* (the book is freely downloadable at his personal web page [here](http://lab7.ipu.ru/eng/people/polyak-p.html), year 1987) states at page 25 the following theorem

Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable and let 
$$ I \ell \le \nabla^2 f(x) \le IL, \quad \ell > 0, \ L \in \mathbb{R} $$
for all $x$. Then for all $0 < \alpha < 2/ L$
$$ || x_k - x^*    || \le ||x_0  - x^*   || q^k , \quad q:= \max \{ |1- \alpha \ell |,|1- \alpha L |  \} < 1$$

where $x^*$ is the unique minimum of the function $f(x)$ and $x_k$ is the $k$-th step of the gradient descent scheme

$$  x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha  \nabla f(x_k) $$
starting at $x_0$.

I am looking for a result of this kind ( where the convergence of gradient descent is proven for $x_k \rightarrow x^*$ and not $f(x_k) \rightarrow f(x^*)$  ) in the case that the objective function $f(x)$ is not strongly convex but just strictly convex or convex, i.e., when

$$ 0 \le \nabla^2 f(x) \le IL, \quad \ L \in \mathbb{R} $$

Comment: When the objective is convex and not strictly convex, it can have multiple global minima. Then, it may be possible that gradient descent does not converge to a single fixed minimizer, but only that any accumulation point converges to a minimizer of $f$. For instance, if the problem is one dimensional and the optimal solution set is $[-1,1]$, it could be (I don't know if such an example exists) that the iterates are $x_k = (1 + \frac{1}{k})(-1)^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Anyway, convergence of objective values is usually sufficient for many applications

Comment: See [this link](https://people.rennes.inria.fr/Cedric.Herzet/Cedric.Herzet/Sparse_Seminar/Entrees/2012/11/12_A_Fast_Iterative_Shrinkage-Thresholding_Algorithmfor_Linear_Inverse_Problems_(A._Beck,_M._Teboulle)_files/Breck_2009.pdf) for results on the rate at which $f(x_k) \to f(x^*)$

Comment: In your question, $\alpha=\gamma$, right?

Comment: what about $f(x)=\log(\exp(x) + \exp(-x)$? (basically a smooth approximation of $g(x)=|x|$) Every step you get at most $\gamma$ closer to the optimum, i.e., sublinear convergence.

Comment: @LinAlg right! I edited

Comment: any thoughts on my example for $f$?